# Looking to open pymongo database connection with decorator

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, decorator, python-decorators

```
@api.route('/api/get_contacts')
def get_contacts():
with pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{mongo_username}:{mongo_password}@dev.glstt.mongodb.net/xxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority") as document:
```

This is too much to look at. I am trying to make it into:

```
@api.route('/api/get_contacts')
@mongo
def get_contacts():
```

The problem is, I don't really understand decorators.
So, this is what I have done so far:

```
def mongo(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap (*args,**kwargs):
        with pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{mongo_username}:{mongo_password}@dev.glstt.mongodb.net/xxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority") as document:

            return f(document)
        return wrap
```

Not sure what I need to do to get the decorator to prepend the code with the 'with operator', and pass x, then the document back to the route function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators works basically by replacing your function, with `decorator(function)`. For instance:

```py
@decorator
def my_function():
    pass
```

Equals to

```py
def my_function():
    pass

my_function = decorator(my_function)
```

It means that you can return a callable function from the decorator, that every time you call it with arguments it will call the decorated function with the particular arguments.

For example:

```py
import functools

def decorator(decorated_function):
    @functools.wraps(decorated_function) # This means that the function that returns from this decorator, "wrapper", will keep the decorated_function's name,  `__doc__` argument and more.
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Every time you will call the function that returned from the decorator, this function will be called with the particular arguments in args and kwargs.
        """
        return decorated_function(*args, **kwargs) + 10
    return wrapper


@decorator
def func(n):
    return n * 2

result = func(2) # here we called the function `wrapper`, the result is func(2) + 10, as we did when we called the function.

print(result) # 14
```

We can also `print(func)` and the result will be something like
`<function func at 0x7f5eb16b0040>`, and if we didn't use `functools.wraps`: `<function decorator.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fba9ba0f040>`.

Now for your question,
when you stack decorators,

```py
@c
@b
@a
def func(): pass
```

the order is
`c(b(a(func)))`
And hence, your function named `mongo` should take the argument "request" from `api.route('/api/get_contacts')`. (I don't know what framework this is, so I can't predict whether this framework supplies the request as a function argument).

if the framework does not pass the request as an argument:

```py
def mongo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrap():
        with pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{mongo_username}:{mongo_password}@dev.glstt.mongodb.net/xxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority") as document:
            return f(document)
    return wrap
```

and if it does:

```py
def mongo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrap(request):
        # do something with the request
        with pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{mongo_username}:{mongo_password}@dev.glstt.mongodb.net/xxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority") as document:
            return f(document)
    return wrap
```

And then it allows you to do this:

```py
@api.route('/api/get_contacts')
@mongo
def get_contacts(document):
    pass
```

Comment: This really helped, thanks for your time.
This is flask and it does not pass the request as an argument.